# JPQL Inserting new entity violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

**UPDATE:** Changed code to be coherent to db model and changed details of the model itself. Also added code of the section that causes the error.

I am trying to implement a small database consulting system in Hibernate with PostgreSQL and having issues with one specific pair of tables. As you can see, it's a system for car rental services, and the tables store drivers and rentals. A driver is supposed to be able to have multiple rentals (but not the other way around).

**Problem Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Driver(
cod_driver SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
cod_client INTEGER,
num_license BIGINT UNIQUE,
expiration_license DATE,
ident_driver BIGINT,

FOREIGN KEY (cod_client) 
    REFERENCES Client(cod_client)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE Rental(
cod_rental SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
cod_plate VARCHAR(10),
cod_dest VARCHAR(10),
cod_driver INTEGER,
date_delivery DATE,

FOREIGN KEY (cod_plate) 
    REFERENCES Vehicle(cod_plate)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,

FOREIGN KEY (cod_dest) 
    REFERENCES Location(cod_location)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,

FOREIGN KEY (cod_driver) 
    REFERENCES Driver(cod_driver)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I did my implementation using Hibernate as follows (short of getters/setters for brevity):

**Driver**

```
@Entity
public class Driver {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer cod_driver;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_client")
private Client client;

private Long num_license;
private Long ident_driver;
private LocalDate expiration_license;
}
```

**Rental**

```
@Entity
public class Rental {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer cod_rental;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_plate")
private Vehicle vehicle;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_dest")
private Location location_dest;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_driver")
private Driver driver;

private LocalDate date_delivery;
```

**Context of PSQLException**

Persist function call in Main.java (clientGet is obtained through successfull queries, and inserts is just a class for queries):

```
            Driver d = new Driver(clientGet, 3294324792L, 321312931L, LocalDate.of(2030, 10, 01));

    inserts.insertEntity(d);
```

insertEntity function:

```
   public void insertEntity(Object o) // Basic insertion of any persistent object
{
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(o);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**Error**

The error I get is this:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: insert or update on table "driver" violates foreign key 
constraint "fkdfq0qhvpkw1dqguk6dv1dsj0t"
Detail: Key (cod_driver)=(3) is not present in table "rental".
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
```

**What I've Considered**

From my understanding, the relationship didn't need to be bidirectional (though I did try to use mappedBy), given that I don't store rentals in driver table.

I just don't understand what constraint could possibly be violated by this. It's as if it expects the value of cod_driver to be already in the rentals table, but a rental entity depends on the pre-existence of the driver existence. SQL for the database doesn't seem to have any constraint like that.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I tried all things I found, but nothing shed any light on this.

Comment: If a rental has many drivers, then you can't possibly have a column cod_driver in the table rental. That would allow each rental to have only one driver, and, possibly, multiple rentals to have the same driver. You want the exact inverse. So driver should have a cod_rental column. That way, multiple drivers can reference the same rental, and that rental thus has all those drivers.

Comment: @JBNizet That really makes sense. I didn't design the schema itself, so that wasn't immediately clear to me... Thank you, I'll see what can be done about correcting that!

Comment: For the future instead of describing the code that causes error, please just paste it

Comment: @JBNizet I followed your advice and turns out that was my mistaken interpretation of the model (actually one driver was supposed to have n rentals, and not the other way around) ... I have corrected the code since, but the same error persists. Do you perhaps have any other views on this?

Comment: You haven't osted the code that causes this error. But the error is self-explanatory: the foreign key constraint fkdfq0qhvpkw1dqguk6dv1dsj0t, which checks that the cod_driver of a driver references a cod_driver of a rental, fails. This foreign key shouldn't exist.

Comment: @JBNizet Clearly, right? I didn't understand where the constraint was coming from. It was the implementation mistake that created it... I had to drop the db and recreate it. So now it works. Thank you :')

Answer (score 0):

use many to many relationship between rental and driver.the same problem i faced once in my PurchaseOrder and PaymentMethods relationship.

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "rental_driver", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rental_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id"))
    private List driver = new List();

Comment: Welcome to Stack. Suggest you to edit code content in code formatted properly to better answer questions. Refer this meta post on adding code blocks https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I can't use many to many because it would imply that drivers can have many rentals and rentals can have many drivers. The nature of the modelling forbids me from implementing the mapping like that...